# How do I enable the pidgin system tray icon?

Tags: unity, indicator, pidgin

I want to enable the System tray icon for Pidgin in Ubuntu 11.10 (with Unity), but I don't see it.

I have to start it again and again from the launcher panel or from the dash.

Is there a workaround to show the system tray icon in Unity? I think it's the same behavior for Skype and some other applications also.

Comment: martu's solution works for **12.04**, shutter icon revealed

Comment: What to do for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?
`$ gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"`
`No such schema 'com.canonical.Unity.Panel'`

Comment: I ended up using this: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/pidgin-indicator-ubuntu-appindicator.html

Answer (score 36, accepted):

#### For 12.10 and older:

execute:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"
```

(from http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/things-to-tweak-after-installing-ubuntu.html)

and remember to set the system tray to "always" in pidgin preferences.

[image]

If the change doesn't take effect immediately, run `unity --replace`

Comment: This fix worked once for me, but I've since lost my system tray icon (even after repeating the fix). I added myself to the list of people affected by https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pidgin/+bug/879950

Answer (score 11):

### For 13.04:

The migration of Pidgin to the new libmessaging-menu API, which caused this issue, is now done for Pidgin, but still under testing. Also, only a Ubuntu 13.04 package is provided so far, but since it does not introduce any dependencies on other stuff from 13.04, I was able to just install it from the PPA of the programmer who fixed it. According to [his instructions](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-messages/+bug/1040259/comments/46), this is what fixed it for me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jconti/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pidgin-libnotify
```

You should now have pidgin-libnotify version 0.14-9ubuntu1. In addition, you have to add the following line to `/usr/share/applications/pidgin.desktop`:

```
 X-MessagingMenu-UsesChatSection=true
```

Then restart Pidgin, it should now get an entry in the message indicator menu of the panel again, so that when closing its window, it stays running.

### Update

It is NOT necessary (any more) to install this repository as of May 23. Probably the updates have been officially included by now.

Just make sure the libnotify plugin is active! With Ubuntu 12.10 (and previous) and the whitelist for system tray icons you/the user may have deactivated the libnotify plugin on purpose.

Comment: That PPA doesn't seem to have build for Raring.

Comment: I tried the suggestions on my Raring installation, but it seems it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

In 11.10 Unity has hidden the system tray access to pidgin under the messaging icon that looks like an envelope. If you click it, there should be an entry for Pidgin. Not exactly what you're looking for, but at least it's accessible somehow via the system tray.

Answer (score 3):

manually:

1. run **dconf-editor**
2. open **desktop** -> **unity** -> **panel**
3. set **systray-whitelist** to **"['all']"**

Comment: Thanks this tweak resolved my problem for a different app!

Comment: I don't see "panel" under desktop->unity?! Using Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-messages/+bug/1040259) they changed the messages indicator and the pidgin indicator is not adapted to these changes. There is a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-desktop/+archive/ppa/) for the recent development but as it says on launchpad:

```
for quantal we will add those soon:
- pidgin
- xchat-indicator
- evolution-indicator
```

meaning we still have to wait for it :-(

If it's finally out you can add the ppa using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

There is no way to tell for sure what package you have to install after that but there is a good chance it will be

```
sudo apt-get install checkbox-unity
```

Answer (score 0):

Under 13.10 the only solution to bring the sys-tray back is:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:timekiller/unity-systrayfix
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I use 14.04.
Adding and upgrading and executing `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"` didn't work out for me. Any idea what would work for the LTS version?