# How to integrate Pidgin on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, pidgin

I have just recently updated my system to Ubuntu 12.10 and I cannot integrate Pidgin with the toolbars any more! Can any one give me a clue on how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By the tool bars, I'm guessing you mean the message indicator menu. In this case, this is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-messages/+bug/1040259

In 12.10, the libindicate API was deprecated and a new API was introduced (libmessaging-menu). If you look at the bug page, many applications are in the process of being ported to this new API, including Pidgin.

Looks like the Pidgin bug is in progress at least, so we'll have to wait this out.

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: I see it says "Pidgin Fix Released", but I'm on Raring and Pidgin still doesn't show up. I have to use its own icon (Settings→Show panel icon always)

Answer (score 1):

Try http://nevitus.com/2013/05/unity-integration-for-pidgin/

Scroll down to the bottom of the post and download the plugin for unity integration in pidgin.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If by integration you mean displaying the icon on top, and minimizing when X is clicked, then you might like to read this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/69644/22899

In short:

1. run dconf-editor
2. open com -> canonical -> unity -> panel
3. set systray-whitelist to "['all']"

Also enable "show system tray icon" in the first preferences screen of Pidgin.

Answer (score -1):

Ciao! prova a dare un'occhio a questo link
https://launchpad.net/~pidgin-developers/+archive/ppa/

Può esserti di aiuto!

--
Translation

Hello! tries to give an eye to this link https://launchpad.net/~pidgin-developers/+archive/ppa/

It may be helpful to!

Comment: English, please. There may be more people interested in the solution.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.