# What IM clients support Jabber and show notifications on the toolbar in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: empathy, notification, pidgin, instant-messaging

I'm migrating from MacOS X back to Ubuntu, and trying to find an IM client I can use.   I use IM quite a bit for work, so I really need to see notifications in the toolbar at the top of the screen.

When I previously used Ubuntu, Pidgin was my go-to IM client, and it's also the one recommended by my company - and it is what I have set up now - however the fact that it doesn't support notifications in the top window is an issue for me.   I've already missed one message from my boss because of the lack of notifications!

Unfortunately Empathy doesn't seem to work with the custom Jabber server my work operates - some people I talked to said that there was a known incompatibility between the two, and no plans to fix it on either side.

Are there other IM clients that are well integrated into Ubuntu and will show a notification in the title bar?

Alternatively, if anyone knows of a trick to get pidgin notifications working, that'd be great - based on the googling I did, it sounds like a known issue that people are working on, but I wasn't able to find a target date for the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the alternative solution with pidgin is possible - this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/69644/22899 seems to do the trick - from the context I thought it only added an icon with controls to the toolbar, but it is the full icon with a notification if there are unread messages...  That solves the problem for me with Pidgin.