# Pidgin status icon in 13.04 / Raring Ringtail

Tags: 13.04, pidgin, notification-area

I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 13.04.

Looks great, but the Pidgin status icon does not appear in the upper right corner.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Starting 13.04, applications will have to integrate into the indicators and can no longer have their own status icons in systray in Unity. (This may change in future.)

> **The Unity systray whitelist has been removed, so you can no longer whitelist applications to allow them to use the notification area in Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail**. However, Java and Wine applications have been hard-coded as the only software still able to use the notification area so this change only affects some old applications that don't come with AppIndicator support. And since Qt applications systray icons are automatically converted to appindicators thanks to `sni-qt`, this change shouldn't affect too many applications.

Source: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/ubuntu-1304-raring-ringtail-final-beta.html

Answer (score 2):

The functions of the former Pidgin icon are integrated into the **messaging icon**, which then will **turn blue** instead of white when new messages have arrived. But it is impossible to distinguish at a glance between new chat messages and new email (e.g. from Thunderbird, XChat, Empathy...).

If Pidgin does not work with the messaging icon in 13.04, this one from a similar question at "[Ubuntu 13.04 Pidgin Tray](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290064/ubuntu-13-04-pidgin-tray)" may hold the solution: Because when using the Pidgin icon with previous Ubuntu versions, you or someone else may have deactivated the libnotify plugin on purpose, which is needed for support of the messaging icon. If that is the case, this is the quick solution:

1. Find the "libnotify Popups" plug-in in Pidgin (Tools menu)
2. activate it
3. configure what kind of popups you want to see (probably none)
4. restart Pidgin.

(It is not necessary anymore to add a developer repository for Pidgin's libnotify plugin, as suggested in "[How do I enable the pidgin system tray icon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67312/how-do-i-enable-the-pidgin-system-tray-icon)" - that problem is fixed.)

But for everyone who still wants Pidgin to have its own original system tray icon, I do recommend the alternative repository for 13.04 of webupd8.org as suggested Peter Paldan in another answer on this page here. It will replace some binaries concerning the Gnome panel where the whitelist in dconf at *com.canonical.Unity.Panel* is still functioning as it should.

Answer (score 1):

There is "HOW TO GET THE SYSTRAY WHITELIST BACK IN UBUNTU 13.04" which look working so far for me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:timekiller/unity-systrayfix
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/05/how-to-get-systray-whitelist-back-in.html