# Ubuntu 13.04 Pidgin Tray

Tags: 13.04, pidgin, messaging-tray

Does not show the current status of pidgin in the system tray.
Status always is Offline.

**how i can fix this?**

*ps: pidgin works fine.*

Comment: and neither does it show notifications upon new messages anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that if you enable the Libnotify Popups plugin (pidgin-libnotify) in Tools->Plugins then this problem is resolved. You can set your status via the system tray menu and you can also close the Pidgin Buddy List window and it will remain running. If you don't want notifications you can also configure this plugin in the Plugins menu.

Answer (score 0):

Other possibility is installing, if you do not have, the plugin for Pidgin called [Ubuntu Indicator](https://github.com/philipl/pidgin-indicator).

Enable this plugin in *Tools* -> *Plugins* and enjoy it!