# How do I make Pidgin display its system tray icon on 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, pidgin, system-tray

Pidgin's page in Software Center says I should install one of gnome-panel or kdebase-workspace-bin or docker to achieve this. I installed docker but nothing happened.

Needless to say, I have "Show system tray icon" set to "Always" in Pidgin's preferences.

This is not a duplicate question, because the Ubuntu 12.10 recipe doesn't apply to 13.04

I said, this question is not a duplicate. I'm saying it again: dconf-editor doesn't show the parameters that the answer on the OTHER question says I should edit. Because this here question refers to 13.04, and not to versions up to 12.10.

Comment: It is still the same, and someone seems to have added a answer for 13.04 http://askubuntu.com/a/276185/47291 , In cases where we have a new version, we usually bounty and add version specifics to the master question, as simply "I'm using a different version" is not enough to differentiate between the questions.